# How to show button in a row only on mouseover?

Tags: css, jsf, user-interface, primefaces, mouseover

I would like to show a close button to be display on a row in a last column (while mouse over on that row)
I don't want the close button to be always visible but just on a mouse over.

[image]

If anyone has an example that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

this is very simple example

css

```
table a{
    display: none;
}
table tr:hover a{
    display: inline;
}
```

and html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>asdasd</td>
        <td><a href="">Close</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>asdasd</td>
        <td><a href="">Close</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>asdasd</td>
        <td><a href="">Close</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>asdasd</td>
        <td><a href="">Close</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>asdasd</td>
        <td><a href="">Close</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>asdasd</td>
        <td><a href="">Close</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i would recomand using opacity not display, beacause the alignment could mess up between displaying it or not.